# PyAutoGUI ImageNotFoundException in Asyncio Thread When Locating Image on Screen

Tags: python

My code worked fine, I installed a older version of python to try some stuff, reinstalled the newest version of python and now im running into an issue, not sure if this is the right place, but I can't find help anywhere else.
I try'd it with version 3.10.10, 3.11.0 and latest.
Im pretty new to python

https://github.com/Tom-Hartmann/Queue-accepter

```
This is the error:
PS D:\VSC\Queue-accepter> & C:/Users/Tom/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python312/python.exe d:/VSC/Queue-accepter/autoaccept.py
DEBUG:asyncio:Using proactor: IocpProactor
Exception in thread Thread-1 (run_coroutine_in_thread):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 172, in wrapper
    return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 204, in locateCenterOnScreen
    return pyscreeze.locateCenterOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 447, in locateCenterOnScreen
    coords = locateOnScreen(image, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 405, in locateOnScreen
    retVal = locate(image, screenshotIm, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 383, in locate
    points = tuple(locateAll(needleImage, haystackImage, **kwargs))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 257, in _locateAll_opencv
    raise ImageNotFoundException('Could not locate the image (highest confidence = %.3f)' % result.max())
pyscreeze.ImageNotFoundException: Could not locate the image (highest confidence = 0.481)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1052, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 989, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "d:\VSC\Queue-accepter\autoaccept.py", line 129, in run_coroutine_in_thread
    loop.run_until_complete(target_function())
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 664, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\VSC\Queue-accepter\autoaccept.py", line 48, in img
    and locate("balance.png")
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "d:\VSC\Queue-accepter\autoaccept.py", line 30, in locate
    location = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(image, confidence=confidence)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Tom\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 174, in wrapper
    raise ImageNotFoundException  # Raise PyAutoGUI's ImageNotFoundException.
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException
```

Comment: I downgraded the library pyscreeze and that fixed the error